# Parameterizing query to return specific values or all values and all NULLs

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am working with a complex query:

```
SELECT DTH.PointPerson AS Person
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN USR.[Deleted] IS NULL
                THEN 'Active'
            ELSE 'Inactive'
            END
        ) AS [Status]
    ,OLT.[Name] AS OrganizationalTeam
    ,PDT.[Name] AS Project
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN TSK.NAME IS NULL
                THEN NULL
            WHEN SPT.[Name] + ' - ' + SPT.[Description] IS NULL
                THEN 'KanBan'
            ELSE SPT.[Name] + ' - ' + SPT.[Description]
            END
        ) AS Sprint
    ,COALESCE(STY.[Number], NSS.IncidentNumber) AS Story
    ,TSK.[Name] AS Task
    ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 2
                    THEN DTH.[Hours]
                ELSE 0
                END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS MondayHours
    ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 3
                    THEN DTH.[Hours]
                ELSE 0
                END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TuesdayHours
    ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 4
                    THEN DTH.[Hours]
                ELSE 0
                END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS WednesdayHours
    ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 5
                    THEN DTH.[Hours]
                ELSE 0
                END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS ThursdayHours
    ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 6
                    THEN DTH.[Hours]
                ELSE 0
                END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS FridayHours
    ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 7
                    THEN DTH.[Hours]
                ELSE 0
                END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SaturdayHours
    ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 1
                    THEN DTH.[Hours]
                ELSE 0
                END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SundayHours
    ,CAST(SUM(DTH.[Hours]) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TotalHours
FROM DailyTaskHours DTH
LEFT JOIN Task TSK ON DTH.TaskId = TSK.PK_Task
LEFT JOIN Story STY ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
LEFT JOIN NonScrumStory NSS ON DTH.NonScrumStoryId = NSS.PK_NonScrumStory
LEFT JOIN Sprint SPT ON STY.SprintId = SPT.PK_Sprint
LEFT JOIN Product PDT ON STY.ProductId = PDT.PK_Product
LEFT JOIN ProductTeamUser PTU ON TSK.ProductTeamUserId = PTU.PK_ProductTeamUser
LEFT JOIN [User] USR ON PTU.UserId = USR.PK_User
LEFT JOIN OrganizationalTeam OLT ON USR.OrganizationalTeamId = OLT.PK_OrganizationalTeam
WHERE DTH.PointPerson LIKE @userParam
    AND ActivityDate >= @startDateParam
    AND ActivityDate <= @endDateParam
    AND OLT.PK_OrganizationalTeam LIKE @orgTeamPK
GROUP BY DTH.PointPerson
    ,PDT.[Name]
    ,SPT.[Name]
    ,SPT.[Description]
    ,STY.[Number]
    ,NSS.IncidentNumber
    ,TSK.[Name]
    ,OLT.[Name]
    ,USR.[Deleted]
HAVING SUM(DTH.[Hours]) > 0
```

The parameters shown above (@orgTeamPK, @startDateParam etc) are assigned based on user drop down menu selection.

It is manipulated via C#:

```
SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["orgTeamPK"].DefaultValue = teamDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
```

Currently, AND OLT.PK_OrganizationalTeam LIKE @orgTeamPK is not working as intended.

There is a dropdown menu that is as follows: Select All, Team A, Team B, ...

When a user selects Select All I want it to show all teams or those which are NULL and not assigned to teams. Currently, my attempt is to pass '%' but it does not return NULLs.

I could do something like this:

AND OLT.PK_OrganizationalTeam LIKE @orgTeamPK OR OLT.PK_OrganizationalTeam IS NULL

This wont work however, because if the user selects Team A, it will and @orgTeamPK is reassigned from % to 'Team A' it will RETURN team A and all of the nulls.

How can I get it to return only Team A when selected, but all NULLs and all teams when Select All is selected?

Comment: `AND (OLT.PK_OrganizationalTeam = @orgTeamPK OR @orgTeamPK = '%')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AND coalesce(OLT.PK_OrganizationalTeam,'') LIKE @orgTeamPK
```

This isn't quite the same thing as the `OR NULL` option, because the empty string won't match your Team A/B conditions.